# Javascript for a class to display: none, if a tab class is open or close (Collapsible Panel)

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I am working on a collapsible panel menu. Everything is looking great except for the title in the collapsible panel tab. So, here's what I'm trying to do, if the collapsible panel content is open, I want the collapsible panel tab to show a specific span class. For example, it will show a minus or (-) sign if it is open. And if it is close, it will show a plus or (+) sign.

Here's the code:

```
<div id="CollapsiblePanel1" class="CollapsiblePanel">
    <div class="CollapsiblePanelTab" tabindex="0">
       <span class="closedmenu">+</span>
       <span class="openmenu">-</span>
    </div>
    <div class="CollapsiblePanelContent"> 
       <ul>
          <li><a href="LINK1urlHERE">LINK1titleHERE</a></li>
          <li><a href="LINK2urlHERE">LINK2titleHERE</a></li>
       </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var CollapsiblePanel1 = new Spry.Widget.CollapsiblePanel("CollapsiblePanel1", {contentIsOpen:false});
</script>
```

Or, if the collapsible panel content is open, I would like the class .closedmenu to have a css of display:none. And if the collapsible panel content is closed, the class .openmenu to have a css of display:none.

In css, the idea is like:

```
.CollapsiblePanelOpen .CollapsiblePanelTab {
   .closedmenu {display:none;} }
.CollapsiblePanelClosed .CollapsiblePanelTab {
   .openmenu {display:none;} }
```

But of course, this does not work. So, I think a javascript is needed.

I need a very simple answer to this one, if anyone can, please. Thank you! I hope this question is clear and understandable. :)

Comment: mind posting a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) ? :)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. I'm trying jsFiddle but for some reason, it's not working. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the hooks you can use in Spry, but you could functions like this:

```
function clickPlus() {
    document.getElementById("openButton").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("closeButton").style.display="inline";
}

function clickMinus() {
    document.getElementById("openButton").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("closeButton").style.display="none";
}
```

And on your spans do something like this:

```
<span id="openButton" onclick="clickPlus();">+</span>
<span id="closeButton" onclick="clickMinus();">-</span>
```

This all assumes that you start off with specifying `display:none;` in your css for `closeButton`.

**EDIT**:  I changed the code to be a bit more specific, and noted the requirement for `display:none;` in the css

Comment: Hi. Thanks for this. However, I'm still confused. I think, partially, I have gotten what I want.
But anyway, what happens is that, default display displays this [ +- ]. Then if it is clicked, it shows this [ - ]. If it is clicked again, it still shows this [ - ]. 
How can I do it in such a way that the default display is [ + ] and if it is clicked, it will show [ - ]. And if clicked again, it will show [ + ]. Thanks again for any answer. 
I'm still trying to learn so I may have not gotten your whole point. Thanks!

Comment: Check the edits I made.  If it displays [+-] in the beginning, that just means you're not putting `display:none;` in your initial css.

Comment: Hi Indigenuity. Thanks so much for the code. Yes. I did try until I got it right. I didn't know that I have to actually put the script inside the head tag to make it work. I kept putting it before the </body tag. And also, resizing the tab to the width of the font size of + and - {Because if not, by clicking anywhere on the tab other than the + or -, the function won't happen}. 

Thanks again. This would definitely help me in my coding career. :)

Comment: Also, this alternative may work (for others who may be looking for an alternative) --> http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?973429-Javascript-for-a-class-to-display-none-if-a-tab-class-is-open-or-close&p=5317866#post5317866